# Segmentation fault when declaring variable inside struct

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

I've recently come across a very strange segfault while developing my application. Basically, if I add another variable to one of my structs, a segfault is caused upon execution, for no apparent reason. Removing this variable immediately solves the problem. The struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct Note {
    char cNote;
    unsigned int uiDuration;
    unsigned int uiVelocity;
};
```

As soon as I add a

```
long lStartTime;
```

variable anywhere in the struct, the code compiles as usual but will throw a segmentation fault. GDB's backtrace is lost somewhere in some obscure WIN methods that I don't even use.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You have undefined behaviour somewhere. Adding this member is just making it more apparent. Do you do anything related to `Note`s that involves manual memory management or accessing arrays? Start looking there.

Comment: To add a bit to Joseph's comment - it is quite possible some code is doing something untoward with memory management or array access, but no relationship whatsoever to `Note`.   One of the joys of undefined behaviour is that symptoms can change when totally unrelated code is edited.

Answer (score 2):

I see several possible explanations:

1. Something somewhere assumes that the `struct` is of a certain size. Changing the size break things.
2. You might have a memory bug of some sort, which is brought to the surface by you changing the layout of things in memory. Try a tool like valgrind or Purify.
3. You are changing the `struct` in a header file, but are failing to rebuild all source files that use the `struct`.

Comment: In addition to valgrind, there's Electric Fence and (Windows-only) App Verifier.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, but I figured it out. Turns out I allocated a large array composed of `Note`s statically inside another class. I should have done this dynamically, since the program's stack isn't big enough to hold so many instances of `Note`. 

Which is quite ironic, since adding a variable to the struct caused the stack to overflow. Just should have looked at the website title, lol.